# Firebase returns multiple IDs, Which is unique one?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase and i am trying to connect Firebase Auth api into my application, I have followed documentation from newer updated documentation from [Official site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and all things work fine.

I have done successful SignIn and in my dashboard i got all users after they login.

My problem is i am so confuse about various IDs returned from Firebase

Code is as follows :

```
 for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
                // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
                String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
                //if Id of the provider is firebase it means we have successfully get back data after saving in firebbase hence we continue to app
                if(providerId.equals("firebase")) {
                    // UID specific to the provider
                    Other.SavePref(this, "LoginToken", profile.getUid());

                    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                    String name = profile.getDisplayName();
                    String email = profile.getEmail();
                    Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();

                    Log.e("userinfo", "  ::  " + profile.getUid()+ " :: " + name + " :: " + email + " :: " + photoUrl);
                }
            };
```

as in above code i am only checking if providerId is firebase then i store information, but if i don't do it, it will give me data two times

1. from Firebase
2. from Google also

and i got two userIds if i use this method : **profile.getUid()**, I just want to know **which one is unique?** and **which i should use?**

And someone can proposed a way for what to do after getting successful signin at application side, It would be very helpful..

Comment: sorry, I didn't get when you say " i got two userIds if i use this method : profile.getUid()" , for single call to method in one time or with different calls  to same ?

Comment: suppose i use method profile.getUid() without checking condition that provider is firebase then it will return id for both firebase as well as google @MKJParekh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user can sign in with multiple providers. Each provider generates its own unique ID for that user. You can access these under the [user info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo.html#getUid()) for each provider.

On top of that Firebase Authentication also generates its own unique ID for the user. No matter which provider the user signed in with, they'll end up with the same UID for that. You can find this under [`FirebaseUser.getUid()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getUid()).

To identify a user, you'd normally use the value from `FirebaseUser.getUid()`, so in your snippet: `user.getUid()`.

Comment: ok but user.getUid() returns what? is it any value from firebase side or google side ?

Comment: It returns an opaque value that uniquely identifies the user. That is the only guarantee that is made about it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Will it be unique across different apps. I have two different app with same backend server.

Comment: UIDs are definitely be unique within a single project (so also across all apps in that project). I think they're also unique across all projects, but I've never had a need to investigate that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there a list of possible provider id somewhere in the documentation? It would be very helpful to see if there is any. (I know providerId can be "facebook.com", "password", but I'd like to know all the possible values).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I'd also like to know this list.

Comment: note - if an auth account gets deleted, and they sign back up, their Firebase `uid` will be different.