# firebase auth - get current provider javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to find out what provider my user is using, and I have no idea how! the language that I use is vanilla javascript. 
There's a very similar question: 
[Firebase Auth - get provider ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291878/firebase-auth-get-provider-id) 
but this only works in swift 3...

Comment: Firebase SDKs are quite consistent across platforms. This means that the same approach should work on JavaScript too. Did you try to map the Swift code to JavaScript yet?

Comment: Yes i have inserted the following line of code into javascript: console.log(FIRAuth.auth().currentUser.providerData); And it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to loop through `providerData` to get the `providerId`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the linked answer and Hareesh said, you will need to loop over the `providerData` array since a user can be signed in with multiple providers. So:

```
user.providerData.forEach(function(providerData) {
    console.log("Signed in with "+providerData.providerId);
});
```

For a working example see: https://jsbin.com/vuzafuq/edit?html,js,output (check the JavaScript console for the actual providers)

Comment: alright alright, I didn't know one could be signed in via multiple providers simultaneously and now that I do, I'm wondering, ...mo providers, mo problems.

Answer (score 6):

**Firebase** provides the currently signed-in provider information inside the user object like below (I have used the **AngularFire** Framework Library for the below example).

For the **web platform**, please refer to the following code:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import 'firebase/auth';

export class AuthenticationService {
   constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }

   getCurrentUser(){
      this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
         if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            user.getIdTokenResult()
                .then((idTokenResult) => {
                  let currentProvider = idTokenResult.signInProvider;
                  // The result will look like  'google.com', 'facebook.com', ...
                 });
         } else {
            // No user is signed in.
         }
      });
    }
}
```

For more details, check out the **official doc** [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.IDTokenResult).

Comment: This is the most current (v9) method and relies on the proper class methods, without needing to manipulate array/object data manually. (thank you)

Current, working official docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usergetidtokenresult
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.idtokenresult.md#idtokenresultsigninprovider

Answer (score 5):

I have tried multiple providers.
If you want to get all providers user have logged in, you can use `user.providerData`.
But the order of providerData is not based on the desc order by user log in time which the Swift SDK claimed.
This doesn't apply to Javascript SDK.

If you want to get current provider, you can decode the idToken which contain current logged in provider `sign_in_provider`.
The format would be something like this

```
{
  .....
  "email": ....,
  "email_verified": true,
  "firebase": {
    "identities": {
      "google.com": [
        ....
      ],
      "email": [
        ....
      ]
    },
    "sign_in_provider": "password"
  }
}
```

You could tried to decode by https://jwt.io/ or using npm package `jsonwebtoken` to decode.
Test on the firebase `7.15.0` and hope this works for you.

Comment: This should be the answer as currently accepted answer just lists providers that user logged in with at least once, not the most recent once user logged in with. (Also the first one of those providers do not show the most recent logged in one, I confirm that)

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 Answer (Firebase v8)

I was looking for a simple little JS snippit and couldn't find one. Maybe this will help you:

```
// Gets the user's sign-in method
let signInMethod =
          firebase.auth().currentUser?.providerData[0]?.providerId;
```