# How to determine which provider the user logged in with

Tags: facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using multiple Firebase sign in methods in my app (Facebook, Google, Phone, etc). But once the user is logged in, I am unable to determine which provider was used to sign in.

I tried below(very close to the [recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291878). But does not work):
_auth.currentUser().providerData[0].providerId

I expect it to return something like "google.com" or "facebook.com" 
Instead it returns "firebase"

I cant find any other solution where it clearly lets us determine if a google or facebook sign in was used. All solutions in the forum iOS specific or for web. Can't find anything flutter specific. Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: The string value should be the same for each platform.  If it's not working as expected for Flutter, that might be a bug in the Flutter library.

Comment: It is same for each platform. The issue is that I cannot determine how the user logged in - using lets say google or facebook

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Auth - get provider ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291878/firebase-auth-get-provider-id)

Answer (score 2):

I checked and _auth.currentUser().providerData[0].providerId does provide "google.com" or "facebook.com"

Not sure at what point it showed me "firebase". Will post to this if I figure this out

Comment: I am currently getting firebase when getting the providerId. This seems to only be happening in Android, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :

```
@override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      final _providerData = _auth.currentUser!.providerData;
      if (_providerData.isNotEmpty) {
        if (_providerData[0]
            .providerId
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains('google')) {
          await GoogleSignIn().signOut(); // google signOut
        } else if (_providerData[0]
            .providerId
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains('facebook')) {
          await FacebookAuth.instance.login(); // facebook signOut
        }
      }
      await _auth.signOut(); // firebase signOut
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about facebook since I have never implemented login with facebook, but for Google, you may be able to do something like this.

You probably have a statement similar to `GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn()`. Why not check if `google User` is `null` or not once the user is signed in or on auth change? This will let you know if the user signed in with google.

Similar functionality for facebook should be possible but I just don't know if it is the same.

If `googleUser != null` then google was used.
If say `facebookUser != null` then facebook was used,
Then if `googleUser` is `null` and say `facebookUser` is `null` it was email.

Maybe this is helpful, maybe not, but it is just what I could think of right now.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. There are many work around like this. Another method is by using Shared Preferences. I am looking for something Firebase given as that will be more scalable

Comment: Totally understand! If I come across something I will let you know! Also if you find the answer please answer your own question here so I can come back and see. Ill star it and upvote it.