# How to get Firebase Provider ID in Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase

I already saw [Firebase Auth - get provider ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291878/firebase-auth-get-provider-id)
but in unity I can't find how to get provider id from providerData
Please Help me

Comment: Follow the getting started on firebase website

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It will be much easier for the community to help you if you explain what you have already tried and post a code sample.  See this link for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you looking for.

```
string currentUserProvider = "";
foreach (Firebase.Auth.IUserInfo d in FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.ProviderData) {

  currentUserProvider = d.ProviderId;
}
```